# Node with SQL Server - response with for json path query not responding as expected

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am working with Node and SQL Server. Everything is fine with simple two dimensional tables, but when I try to do a nested query with a `for json path` response, I get an unexpected result I don't know how to solve with node.js

Here is my code:

```
let sqlString = `
SELECT        codeid, code, validFrom, validTo,
(SELECT        dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.productIdentifier, dbo.masterGroupsProducts.productName, dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.compensation
FROM            dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp INNER JOIN
dbo.masterGroupsProducts ON dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.productIdentifier = dbo.masterGroupsProducts.productIdentifier
WHERE        (dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.codeid = dbo.PLprospectAgentCodes.codeid) for json path ) as products
FROM            dbo.PLprospectAgentCodes
WHERE        (plid = ${userData.plid}) for json path`


let conn = await sql.connect(process.env.DB_CONNSTRING)
let recordset = await conn.query(sqlString)
if (recordset.rowsAffected[0] > 0) {
    jsonResponse.success = 1
    jsonResponse.data = recordset.recordset;
}
else {
    JsonResponse.success = 0;
    JsonResponse.message = "ERR 1:Invalid credentials";
}


res.json(jsonResponse)
await conn.close();
```

Everything was fine until I utilized for json auto at my sql string, which I need in order to get the results the way I need them.

I tried stringyfying, .toString(), JSON.parse, nothing worked, and this is the result I get:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "[{\"codeid\":1,\"code\":\"pablo\",\"validFrom\":\"2020-01-01\",\"validTo\":\"2022-01-01\",\"products\":[{\"productIdentifier\":\"Sigma\",\"productName\":\"Sigma Tramma\",\"compensation\":28.00},{\"productIdentifier\":\"membership\",\"productName\":\"Membership\",\"compensation\":30.00}]},{\"codeid\":2,\"code\":\"paola20\",\"validFrom\":\"2021-01-01\",\"validTo\":\"2020-01-01\",\"products\":[{\"productIdentifier\":\"Sigma\",\"productName\":\"Sigma Tramma\",\"compensation\":18.00},{\"productIdentifier\":\"membership\",\"productName\":\"Membership\",\"compensation\":20.00}]}]"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this, from either the query, or Node?

Thanks.

Comment: If you execute that query in SSMS you'll see that the single column holding the JSON response has a JSON_guidy name similar to the one posted in the question. If you want a fixed column name you'll need to move the existing code into a subquery such as `select ( ...your JSON query here... ) as YourPreferredColumnName;`

Comment: You have dangerous SQL injection going on here, use proper parameters

Comment: Hi Carlie. Really? How can I fix it? Ive read this on Microsoft: "All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection. This is because it is rendered as prepared statement, and thus all limitations imposed in MS SQL on parameters apply. e.g. Column names cannot be passed/set in statements using variables."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As AlwaysLearning said, try

```
let sqlString = `
select (SELECT        codeid, code, validFrom, validTo,
(SELECT        dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.productIdentifier, dbo.masterGroupsProducts.productName, dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.compensation
FROM            dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp INNER JOIN
dbo.masterGroupsProducts ON dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.productIdentifier = dbo.masterGroupsProducts.productIdentifier
WHERE        (dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.codeid = dbo.PLprospectAgentCodes.codeid) for json path ) as products
FROM            dbo.PLprospectAgentCodes
WHERE        (plid = ${userData.plid}) for json path) as data`
```

This will result in

```
 {
        "success": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "data": "[{\"codeid\":1,\"code\":\"pablo\",\"validFrom\":\"2020-01-01\",\"validTo\":\"2022-01-01\",\"products\":[{\"productIdentifier\":\"Sigma\",\"productName\":\"Sigma Tramma\",\"compensation\":28.00},{\"productIdentifier\":\"membership\",\"productName\":\"Membership\",\"compensation\":30.00}]},{\"codeid\":2,\"code\":\"paola20\",\"validFrom\":\"2021-01-01\",\"validTo\":\"2020-01-01\",\"products\":[{\"productIdentifier\":\"Sigma\",\"productName\":\"Sigma Tramma\",\"compensation\":18.00},{\"productIdentifier\":\"membership\",\"productName\":\"Membership\",\"compensation\":20.00}]}]"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then you can

```
let parsedResponse=JSON.parse(apiResponse.data[0].data);
console.log(parsedResponse)
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: pvg1975 you absolute legend!