# Node and SQL Injection by using ${variable} on query string

Tags: node.js

I was told on a question that Im having a SQL Injection problem.

Here is the question

[Node with SQL Server - response with for json path query not responding as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341001/node-with-sql-server-response-with-for-json-path-query-not-responding-as-expec)

and here is my code

```
let sqlString = `
SELECT        codeid, code, validFrom, validTo,
(SELECT        dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.productIdentifier, dbo.masterGroupsProducts.productName, dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.compensation
FROM            dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp INNER JOIN
dbo.masterGroupsProducts ON dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.productIdentifier = dbo.masterGroupsProducts.productIdentifier
WHERE        (dbo.PLprospectAgentCodesComp.codeid = dbo.PLprospectAgentCodes.codeid) for json path ) as products
FROM            dbo.PLprospectAgentCodes
WHERE        (plid = ${userData.plid}) for json path`


let conn = await sql.connect(process.env.DB_CONNSTRING)
let recordset = await conn.query(sqlString)
```

But I've read at Microsoft, and even on a question on this site, that that format prevents SQL injection.

From MS:

> "All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection. This is
> because it is rendered as prepared statement, and thus all limitations
> imposed in MS SQL on parameters apply. e.g. Column names cannot be
> passed/set in statements using variables."

I was trying to use the declare @parameter for the above code, but since my code has several queries that depend one of another, Im using await for each Query... and @parameter is not working. After I process the recordset, other queries will execute.

If my code actually is dangerous for SQL injection, is it possible to sanitize sqlString before the following two lines? The reason I ask is not to change the method in about 50 routes.

```
let sqlString = `select * from table where userid=${userId}`
```

> Sanitizing code here

```
let conn = await sql.connect(process.env.DB_CONNSTRING)
    let recordset = await conn.query(sqlString)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/ , "All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection." applies only when you use the ES6 Tagged template literals. You should add the tag `sql.query` before the template string.

```
let sqlString = sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
```

For more information on tagged template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Comment: Hi Ricky. So I should basically copy the string inside sql.query and get rid of the sqlString variable?

Comment: @PabloVarela You can assign the tagged template literals to `sqlString`. I edited my answer.

Comment: `sql.query` work as a function being applied on the template string, which do the sanitization for you. It is not a stored value. You have to store and use it return value.